# AS3 : How to identify which button was pressed?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a `MovieClip` with a button inside it named `t_bt`. I have exported that `MovieClip` to action script and gave it a class name of `e_panel` . I created 50 instances of `e_panel` to stage with this code:

```
var e_p_y:Number=0;

for ( var i:Number=1;i<=50;i++)
{
    var e_p:MovieClip = new e_panel();
    e_p.x = 50;
    e_p.y = e_p_y;
    e_p.t_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, f1);
    addChild(e_p);
    e_p_y = e_p_y+105;
}
```

now I want identify which button was pressed by user in function f1.

```
function f1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //...what should I write here?
}
```

Comment: getChildIndex(DisplayObject(event.currentTarget))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every event has a property called `currentTarget`,  which will be a reference to the object you added the event listener to.

So in your case:

```
function f1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     var t_bt:DisplayObject = event.currentTarget as DisplayObject; //would be the t_bt instance that was clicked (typed as a basic object)
     var e_p:MovieClip = DisplayObject(event.currentTarget).parent as MovieClip //would be the e_p of the item clicked

     //so if you wanted to do something like make the whole panel half transparent once clicked
     e_p.alpha = .5;

     //if you wanted to get the index of the button clicked
     trace("Button Clicked: ", e_p.parent.getChildIndex(e_p));
}
```

In contrast, the `target` property of an event is the actual displayObject that was clicked (which could be the same as `currentTarget` or a child of the `currentTarget`)

Comment: thanks @LDMS , but I added 50 items of e_p by addChild,all of them have e_p parent name and t_bt currentTarget, how to identify which button was pressed by user?

Comment: What do you want to do to "identify" it?  My example gives you a reference to the single object that was clicked.  Not sure what you want to actually do with item that was clicked.

Comment: You could use the name property if you just want a label attached to each item

Comment: I knew how to identify a single object, but I said I add 50 e_panel to stage and after that , I want identify which button was pressed by user, I mean I have 50 button on stage that created by addchild, and when user press one of them , how can I understand which button was pressed?

Comment: As is my answer, `event.currentTarget` is the button (out of the 50) that was pressed. If you want an index (which is what others seem to think you want but wasn't a part of your question),  you can use `DisplayObject(event.currentTarget).parent.getChildIndex(DisplayObject(event.currentTarget));`

Comment: I updated my answer to hopefully be clearer...   just try it by replacing your current `f1` method with the one I provided.

Comment: thanks again , your f1 function work exactly right :)

Answer (score 0):

e_panel clip must have an associated E_Panel class that extends MovieClip and (for example) adds an index property to hold the index of the item.

Then, on f1 you could do:

```
function f1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var e_panel:E_Panel = event.currentTarget.parent as E_Panel;
    trace(e_panel.index);
}
```

Remember to set index property upon movie clip creation

Hope it helps

**Extra info**

Create this a class for E_Panel and link it to movieClip with library properties

```
public class E_Panel extends MovieClip 
{

    private var _index:int;

    public function E_Panel(index:int) 
    {
        super();
        _index = index;
    }

    public function get index():int {
        return _index;
    }
}
```

Then in your code:

```
var e_p:E_Panel = new e_panel(i); //"i" is the iteration counter
e_p.x = 50;
... //Etc
```

Comment: thanks @edrian , how to set index property upon movie clip creation?

Comment: @Fanous I added extra info

Comment: @edrian - heads up - `event.currentTarget` will actually be the `b_t` instance, not the the `E_Panel`.

Comment: Thanks @LDMS!, if b_t is child of e_panel you could access it through event.currentTarget.parent

Comment: @edrian - yup,  though you may need to cast before accessing the parent property to avoid a compiler error.

Answer (score -1):

Try this Code::

```
var e_p_y:Number=0;
for ( var i:Number=1;i<=50;i++)
{
    var e_p:MovieClip= new e_panel();
    e_p.x=50;
    e_p.y=e_p_y;
    e_p.t_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, f1);
    addChild(e_p);
    e_p_y=e_p_y+105;

    e_p.name= i+'';

}
```

Now write this code in f1 function::

```
function f1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(event.currentTarget.name);
}
```

Comment: I think it trace just "t_bt" , not name of e_p!